# Breaking out of a python for loop using pygame events

Tags: python, for-loop, event-handling, pygame

I am having an issue breaking out of a for loop in python, using pygame.  Specifically, I'm trying to break out of the loop on release of a key.  For example when key "W" is held down, the code should execute, but then *immediately* break out of loop when the "W" is released.

I have tried to use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` and `if event.type == KEYUP:` but I cannot seem to get it right.  Can anyone help?

```
while 1:
  for event in pygame.event.get():   
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
      doQuitStuff()
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      doMouseButtonStuff()
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_p:
        doPStuff()
      elif event.key == pygame.K_e:
        doEStuff()
      elif event.key in foo:
        doFooStuff()
        for i in xrange(100):
          doThisStuffOnlyIfKeyInFooIsHeldDown() #This for loop finishes
                                                #execution even if I release the
                                                #key in "foo"
```

Comment: you have to do without `for` loop - but with `if do_again:` and main `while` will work as loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do without `for` loop - and `while True` will do as loop.

```
run_loop = False
i = 0

while True:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
           if event.key == pygame.K_w:
              # start loop
              run_loop = True
              i = 0

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
           if event.key == pygame.K_w:
              # stop loop
              run_loop = False

    # - updates -

    if run_loop and i < 100:
        i += 1
        doThisStuffOnlyIfKeyInFooIsHeldDown() 

    # - draws -
```

Comment: Thanks - you have helped me once again!